# How can I import a library that was already imported from a parent script?

Tags: python, import, module, package, parent

I don't know how to be clear and precise about explaining this question...

But I'm trying to run a main script (main.py), that imports several libraries (like the 'os' module) and this script should import another child script (child.py).

The problem is the 'child.py' must use this 'os' module but it can't get from the 'main.py'.

I tried to run 'main.py' and get:
`NameError: name 'os' is not definied.`

My directories structure:

```
main/
|__ main.py
|__ sub/
    |__ child.py
    |__ __init__.py
```

[main.py] content:

```
import os
from sub.child import function

function()
```

[child.py] content:

```
def function:
    os.system('clear')
    <more code that require 'os' module>
```

What am I missing here?
I'm trying to import all libraries from the 'main.py' to avoid waiting to much when running another scripts (don't want them importing a lot of libraries after, I want to import everything from the main file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to import all libraries from the 'main.py' to avoid waiting to much when running another scripts (don't want them importing a lot of libraries after, I want to import everything from the main file).

This is not how it works. You should import a module in the module that actually uses it and only there.

So you need to import the `os` module in the child module to be able to use it:

```
# child.py
import os

def function():
    os.system('clear')
    # more code that uses `os`
```

And if don't actually use `os` in `main.py`, you shouldn't import it there:

```
# main.py
from sub.child import function

function()
```

Also as @user10987432 pointed; if you are worried about `import` statements slowing your code down, then you've got your priorities mixed up. Not only is it a form of premature optimization, but on top of that, it's hard to even think of a time where an `import` statement was the bottleneck - that is to say - it's probably not possible and it's a non-problem.

Comment: `You should import a module in the module that actually uses it and only there.` That's true as Zen of Python told us `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: In addition, I would add that if you are worried about `import` statements slowing your code down, then you've got your priorities mixed up. Not only is it a form of premature optimization, but on top of that, I can't even think of a time where an `import` statement was the bottleneck - that is to say - I don't think it's possible and it's a non-problem.

Comment: @ruohola By all means.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that Folks. It makes sense to use all imports in the own module to make it more 'portable'.

Comment: I already marked it. Thanks. Just to make sure (if anyone search for this question), I missed the `()` on `def function`... I don't know if python accept this without parenthesis.

Comment: @ViníciusValente Yeah, also missed the missing `()`, fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code didn't originally have the import os line in it but you corrected this in the source and re-imported the file.

The problem is that Python caches modules. If you import more than once, each time you get back the same module - it isn't re-read. The mistake you had when you did the first import will persist.

To re-import the imtools.py file after editing, you must use reload(imtools).